# Why does Unity give an error when adding an object to a list using new()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arraylist, new-operator

I have the following code in Unity

```
public class Objects : MonoBehaviour
{
List<GridObject> Grid = new List<GridObject>();
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       Grid.Add( new (GridObject) {xCord = 0, zCord = 0, ObjectID = 0}); 
    }
}
```

And it gives the Error: "Tuple must contain at least two Elements" at GameObject
I think it's related to the new() function but i don't know how

Comment: Why is `GridObject` wrapped in parentheses? Is that a typo?

Comment: Did you mean `new GridObject()` ?

Comment: @derHugo yes that would have been the right one

Comment: @gunr2171 No, that's not just a typo, that was how i thought it was right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the new function is sometimes listed as "new()", the correct format for using it is actually new [object type]()

For example

```
    var someObject = new object();
```

So in your case you would want

```
    public class Objects : MonoBehaviour
    {
    List<GridObject> Grid = new List<GridObject>();
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
        }
    
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
           Grid.Add( new GridObject() {xCord = 0, zCord = 0, ObjectID = 0}); 
        }
    }
```

Additionally, if you want to isolate the error you could create the new GridObject first, and then add it to the list

```
var gridObject = new GridObject {xCord = 0, zCord = 0, ObjectID = 0};
Grid.Add(gridObject);
```

And a little unrelated, but are you intending to add a new GridObject to the grid on every frame, as that is what this code will currently do?

[Microsoft documentation on new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator)

Comment: "And a little unrelated, but are you intending to add a new GridObject to the grid on every frame, as that is what this code will currently do?"

No that's just temporary, because i wanted to first get to make the system before i would be using the system

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo) ;)

Comment: I would say it was less a typo and more of a misunderstanding of how to use new() (and was confirmed by the OP in a comment), which i explained and provided documentation for. Not sure that deserves a down vote...

Comment: @derHugo should we not answer a question where the problem is that the poster does not understand how to use a function? ;)

Comment: It's a pretty straight forward typo .. or at least I would claim that it is that basic `c#` syntax that it won't help any future readers ;)